# change spelling when page loads with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm using a twitter widget that uses twitter api http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js to bring in the latest tweet from my twitter. along the bottom the widget has three links 'reply · retweet · favorite' i need to correct 'favorite' so that its in the british spelling( 'favourite') with a 'u' in it. i thought i could do this with jquery:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $(".twtr-fav").text('Favourite');
});
```

but this doesnt seem to work. any ideas?

Comment: Looks all right - do you actually have an element with `class="twtr-fav"`? (if it's `id="twtr-fav"`, you want `$('#twtr-fav')` instead: `.` is the class selector, `#` is the id selector).

Comment: ye its definitely a class. ive just tried $(".twtr-fav").hide() though and this has no affect! which is really confusing because its definitely there when i use 'inspect element' in chrome

Comment: Does this element exist when page is loaded, or is it generated dynamically? (the easiest way to check is to add `console.debug($(".twtr-fav").size());` into your function - if the element exists at that time, you should see "1" in Chrome's console) Also, is this a problem in all A-class browsers, or is this browser-specific?

Comment: You're most likely trying to select the element before it's actually injected into the DOM via the widget.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the code.  This is a templating system with no callback when it adds something new.  I can't think of any sort of events that it will automatically fire when it adds something...

Your best bet will likely be to patch (urk) the source code.  I'd start from the official base documented twitter code:  http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js

It is a simple one-line change (on line 789), but it can't be monkey patched because there isn't a global object (exactly why I hate that style of function wrapping).

Would be overjoyed for anyone to point out the holes in my logic or knowledge base, but that's how I see it.

---

Added:
I figured out what was gnawing at the back of my mind... there is a way to detect when dom nodes are added:

`document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',favoriteChanger);`  You probably want to call that only after everything is up & running on the site... and you'll need to put a check into favoriteChanger to handle only events that are coming through that are children of the target widget (as *ANY* object will show up otherwise).  Also, you may have issues on downlevel IE.

Comment: $(window).load(function () {

        timeMsg();
    });
   
    function timeMsg() {
        var t = setTimeout("alertMsg()", 800);
    }
    function alertMsg() {
        $(".twtr-fav").text("Favourite");
    }

Comment: Nope.  you'd have to poll because the widget updates over time.

Comment: @phil - Oh, and to be crystal... polling would be a really bad thing to do here.